# firestore permission denied to read data

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I've set the permission rule for testing to allow all read and write based to the firestore documentation using this

```
// Allow read/write access to all users under any conditions
// Warning: **NEVER** use this rule set in production; it allows
// anyone to overwrite your entire database.
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

but i'm still being returned `ERROR Error: permission_denied at /employee: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.`

I've set the environment as per the firestore configuration so I'm not too sure what has went wrong in reading the collection documents.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the client code that isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: Are you using Firestore or the Real Time Database?